# Excel Web App Display Blank

Tags: sharepoint-online

Just would like to ask if you were able to encounter a blank excel web app upon opening the file in a browser. How to fix this?

Thank you.

Regards,
Mars B.

Answer (score 0):

What is the contents inside your Excel file. Is there any images any custom things or its simple data. Try adding a simple excel file with minimum data and check if it opens.

Comment: It is a very simple contact list data.

Comment: It is a contact list information but there are some characters in it. Is this the reason of the error?

Comment: You can try out..remove those characters and check if thats an issue

Comment: I have had similar issue with excel file but once i changed xls to xlsx it worked for me.